# Is there an Item insurance in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

This has rised in mind probably to someone else too. How would item insurance work in pathfinder?

Items like otherworldly kimono, you'd capture the high lord of kingdom in it, take over the kingdom and throw your kimono into a fiery pits of abyss where the lord is then released after x minutes and dies.

Would you be compensated from your insurance issuer for your kimono or not?

Comment: It is just in general mechanics if that can be found in the system that could be incorporated. Apparently it needs homehowbrewery then?

Comment: The site isn't very good at helping users *develop* ideas; that's better suited to one of the forums in [this link.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) However, once you've developed these rules and want them critiqued for game balance and campaign impact, you can post your homebrew rules on the site and users would be happy to evaluate them.

Comment: All other issues aside, why would an insurer compensate you for purposeful destruction of your own property?

Comment: That's why you don't dump Bluff, Magua